# cck dynamic select list in a array

Tags: entities

I have used the code like this

```
$ch2 = curl_init("http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$currency = json_decode($json2);

$opts = '';
foreach($currency as $key => $val)
{
$opts .=$key.'=>'.$val.',';
}

return array($opts);
```

Here I am getting the combo like this everything in a single line

```
AED=>United Arab Emirates Dirham,AFN=>Afghan Afghani,ALL=>Albanian Lek,...
```

What can I do for all the currencies listing 1 by 1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$ch2 = curl_init("http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$currency = json_decode($json2);

return (array)$currency;
```

Comment: Jazakallah !!!!!!! Thank you very much ... Its working